# Why is Jack upset suddenly in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

In *L.A Confidential* (1997), Exley visited Miss Bracken, who works for Pierce Patchett’s Fleur-de-Lis service,
to inquire about her meeting with Bud White. However, things took an unexpected
turn when Exley and Miss Bracken made out and were photographed by Sid.
Meanwhile, Jack was seen leaving a building and fidgeting with his
lighter before putting it away:

> Jack: Come on. **Shit**.

Then Jack drives to Dudley’s and they discuss past collaboration involving Buzz Meeks
and Dick Stensland. During the conversation, Jack is shot by Dudley.

Why is Jack upset suddenly in this scene?

Comment: Did the lighter light?

Comment: @Tetsujin He is **fidgeting** with his lighter, not trying to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's waiting for Exley to show up so they can compare notes on their joint investigation.

But Exley is occupied with Lynn Bracken and is late for their meeting.

Exasperated, Jack makes the mistake of going to Dudley's house to ask his advice